# The proof of Generic Model Theorem (14.5) in Jech's Set Theory p.218

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, filters, forcing

> **Corollary 14.12.** For every partially ordered set $(P,<)$ there is a complete Boolean algebra $B=B(P)$ and a mapping $e:P\to B^+$ such that:
>
> (i) if $q\leq p$ then $e(q)\leq e(p)$;
>
> (ii) $p$ and $q$ are compatible if and only if $e(p)\cdot e(q)\neq 0$;
>
> (iii) $\{e(p)\mid p\in P\}$ is dense in $B$.
>
> $B$ is unique up to isomorphism.
>
> **Theorem (reduced).** Let $M$ be a transitive model of ZFC and let $(P,<)$ be a notion of forcing in $M$. If $G\subseteq P$ is generic over $M$, then there exists a transitive model $M[G]$ such that $G\in M[G]$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   Let $B=B(P)$ and let $M^P=M^B$. Now we define $G$-*interpretation* of $P$: For every $x\in M^P$,
>
> (i) $\emptyset^G=\emptyset$,
>
> (ii) $x^G=\{y^G\mid (\exists p\in G)e(p)\leq x(y)\}$.
>
> We let $M[G]=\{x^G\mid x\in M^P\}$.
>
> Now let $H$ be the generic ultrafilter on $B$ generated by $e(G)$:
>   $$H=\{u\in B\mid (\exists p\in G)e(p)\leq u\}.$$
>   It is easily seen that $x^G=x^H$ for all $x\in M^B$. Thus $M[G]=M[H]$.
>   To verify that $G\in M[G]$, observe that $G=\{p\in P\mid e(p)\in H\}$.$\Box$

I don't know how to verify that $\{p\in P\mid e(p)\in H\}\subseteq G$. Let $p\in P$ such taht $e(p)\geq e(q)$ for some $q\in G$. I need to check that $p\in G$.

It seems that we can have this statement about filter and Boolean algebra:

> If $G\subseteq P$ is generic, then for all $q\in G$ and $p\in P$, $q\leq p$ iff $e(q)\leq e(p)$.

I suppose that $q\nleq p$, then since $p$ and $q$ are compatible, there is $r\in P$ such that $r\leq q$ and $r\leq p$, but it seems not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier to see at first under the assumption that $P$ is separative, and then realize that the requirement about $e$ preserving the compatibility is really about "embedding the separative quotient" into the process.

Let's work with your assumptions, $e(p)\geq e(q)$ and $q\in G$. That means that every condition which is compatible with $q$ is necessarily compatible with $p$. But this means that under assumption of separativity, $p\geq q$, so $p\in G$.

Your gap is that you don't assume that $P$ is separative, which means that you cannot finish the proof. But you need to ask yourself, how would a generic filter look like on a non-separative partial order. Then, when you realize that it is—again—just implicitly including the separative quotient in the process, and we're done.

Comment: Sorry I don't got it; I arrived that $h(G)\subseteq Q$ is generic where $Q$ is the separative quotient of $P$ ($h : P \to Q)$ and $h(p)\in h(G)$. Now there is a  $r\in G$ such that $z$ is compatible with $r$ iff $z$ is compatible with $p$. Can you give more details?

Comment: In the non-separative case, prove that if $p$ is compatible with every extension of $q$, then $q\in G$ implies $p\in G$. This has nothing to do with the question anymore, it's an independent fact.